# Can I assign multiple values to a variable in RobotFramework? And When I use the variable make it randomly select one of them?

Tags: selenium, variables, robotframework, assign

I need to assign multiple values to a variable, and when I use the variable I need it to pick one of the values randomly.
I use Robot Framework.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use Python code with [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate):

```
@{NAMES}=    Create List    Peter    Paul    Mary
${GENDER}=    Evaluate    random.randint(1, 2)    modules=random    # GENDER male=1 female=2
@{RName}=    Evaluate    random.sample(${NAMES}, 1)    modules=random    # Pick a Name
${NAME}=    Convert to String    ${RName[0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use List to store your variables like

```
LIST__abc = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and This is how you can access the values

```
${abc[1]}
```

Comment: Thanks, And If I want to select a random Value?